# Multiple files in same package in Go

Tags: go

I'm writing my first Go code which among other things, sends an email. After finding out that the package `net/smtp` only supports `Plain Auth` (but some providers like outlook doesn't support it), I asked for a solution and got pointed out to https://gist.github.com/andelf/5118732.

That code works like a charm, but as it's not something written by myself, I would like to add it in a separate file and just reference it in my `main.go`.

What's the right approach to have multiple files in the same package? I don't want to create a different package just for that code, first because it's not mine, and secondly, because I think it's an "overkill" approach, isn't it?

I thought that as long as the files are in the same directory, I could have many `*.go` files, but it seems it's not working out. If I just create a file with the content of that gist, the compiler fails because `expected package, found import`. If I add something like `package auth`, then it fails because `found packages auth (auth.go) and main (main.go)`

So, what's the general practice in this situations? Just create packages for everything?

Comment: You can have as many files in a directory as you want and they can be part of the same package as long as you use the same *package declaration* at the top of each file. i.e. change `package auth` to `package main` in the auth file.

Comment: @mkopriva ahh I got that info wrong, I thought that a package's name must be unique, meaning that only one definition of `package foo` could exist. Working fine now in two files.

Comment: You might find "How to Write Go Code" an informative source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have only one package in a directory, and it looks like you don't need a package for this addition, so you can simply put that in a separate file, and add `package main` at the top. Having a `main` package and putting everything under it works up to a point. As things get larger, you have to break it up into self-contained packages.

Answer (score 3):

If your current working directory is in GOPATH, then you can just add new go file with same package name `main`.

If your current working directory is not in GOPATH, you can still put them in multiple go files and when you run the program, you should use `go run *.go` instead of just `go run main.go`.

There are also other options which you can refer [Run code with multiple files in the same main package in GoLang](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1621090998-Run-code-with-multiple-files-in-the-same-main-package-in-GoLang) for detail.